# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'flatten'

Tags: numpy, opencv, python

can I know how to solve this error.

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'flatten'

```
for i in indexes.flatten():
    x, y, w, h = boxes[i]
    label = str(classes[class_ids[i]])
    confidence = str(round(confidences[i],2))
    color = colors[i]
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), color, 2)
    cv2.putText(img, label + " " + confidence, (x, y+20), font, 2, (255, 255, 255),2)
```

Comment: for output in layerOutputs:
        for detection in output:
            scores = detection[5:] #to extract the classes prediction starting from the sixth element to the end
            class_id = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[class_id]
            if confidence > 0.5:
                center_x = int(detection[0]*width)
                center_y = int(detection[1]*height)
                w = int(detection[2]*width)
                h = int(detection[3]*height)

                x = int(center_x - w/2)
                y = int(center_y - h/2)

Comment: boxes.append([x,y,w,h])
                confidences.append((float(confidence)))
                class_ids.append(class_id)

    print(len(boxes))
    indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.5, 0.4)
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
    colors = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(len(boxes),3))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you solved this already.
**You have to check for 0 length indexes before the for loop like this**:

```
if len(indexes) > 0:
    for i in indexes.flatten():
        ....
```

That way it won't enter the for loop when indexes length is 0 which is causing the error.

Regards!

Comment: Yes, it worked already which is the same as yours here. thank u very much.